# Acts-As_Taggable & Administrate Gem - uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::TagDashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I am getting this error: ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::TagDashboard Did you mean? PlanDashboard GoalDashboard TaskDashboard

I really want it to be UserDashboard but not sure what I need to add below or change. Any ideas? Many thanks.

---

So I set up my Adminstrate gem, I am able to show my Models (including User). 
But when I click on Edit, I get the error above.

I am using the following related gems

```
ruby "2.3.1"

gem "rails", "5.0.0.1"

gem "pg", "0.18.4" # postgresql database
gem "acts-as-taggable-on", git: "https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on" # tagging
gem "administrate", git: "https://github.com/heyogrady/administrate", branch: "rails5"
```

Below is my code:

```
enter code here`require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class UserDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard

  # ATTRIBUTE_TYPES
  # a hash that describes the type of each of the model's fields.
  #
  # Each different type represents an Administrate::Field object,
  # which determines how the attribute is displayed
  # on pages throughout the dashboard.
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    owned_taggings: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging"),
    owned_tags: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag"),
    team_group: Field::BelongsTo,
    lead_groups: Field::HasMany,
...
  }

  # COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed on the model's index page.
  #
  # By default, it's limited to four items to reduce clutter on index pages.
  # Feel free to add, remove, or rearrange items.
  COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :name,
    :email,
...
  ]

  # SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed on the model's show page.
  SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = ATTRIBUTE_TYPES.keys

  # FORM_ATTRIBUTES
  # an array of attributes that will be displayed
  # on the model's form (`new` and `edit`) pages.
  FORM_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :owned_taggings,
    :owned_tags,
    :team_group,
    :lead_groups,
...
  ]

  # Overwrite this method to customize how users are displayed
  # across all pages of the admin dashboard.
  #
  def display_resource(user)
    user.name
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the lines involving `Tags` in `ATTRIBUTE_TYPES` like so:

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
# taggings: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging"),
# base_tags: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag"),
# tag_taggings: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging"),
# tags: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag"),
# topic_taggings: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging"),
# topics: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag"),
user: Field::BelongsTo,
tag_list: Field::String,
id: Field::Number,
title: Field::String,
body: Field::Text,
```

Also remove the lines involving `Tags` in `COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`, `SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES`, and `FORM_ATTRIBUTES`.

If you want to display/edit the tags on a model, add this line to `ATTRIBUTE_TYPES`:

`tag_list: Field::String,`

and now you can make use of `:tag_list,` in `COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES`, `SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES`, and `FORM_ATTRIBUTES`.